# Windows RT: Snapped mode Change GridView to ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, gridview, windows-runtime

When my app is snapped displaying a `GridView` isn't the best way to present the information. I want to present it in a `ListView` instead. I also want to change the item template as well.

I currently have a `UserControl` that accepts the `DataContext` as the item template so I can simply create a new view and use that instead and it should work. So I'm basically looking to swap `local:NormalDetailView` with `local:SnappedDetailView`

Originally I thought about having both the ListView and GridView in there at the same time and adjusting the visibility based on snapped mode. But I had doubts about the performance about this technique.

Lastly, this is a `LayoutAwarePage` so I do have all that XAML stuff at the bottom about `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` etc.

```
    <GridView x:Name="GalleryGridView"ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfItems}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:NormalDetailView VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="250" Height="250"  DataContext="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance is just fine if you use both a gridview and a listview, and adjust visibility depending on view state. This is exactly what the "split-application" template in Visual Studio does.

Just generate an app based on this template and take a look at ItemsPage.xaml and ItemsPage.xaml.cs. The other templates may also do this, but I haven't used them so I don't know for sure.